# vscode : problem with format laravel blade inside javascript

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, format, laravel-blade, code-snippets

I try to use blade functions inside javascript but formating result is very Irregular and illegible
And what's worse is that after formatting vscode create white spaces between text and the code does not run
how can fix this

before format :

[befor format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lM1u.png)

after format :

[after format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wuoq.png)

Comment: i had the same issue with vscode.what i did was turned off auto formatting and when i need to format a page, what i do is select all code and press shift+ctrl+i (for ubuntu, different for other os).

Comment: sound likes this is best temporary solution for now
I split the code and put it to component so i can format all document faster

Answer (score 0):

I found that the Laravel-Blade by amirmarmul formatted blade directives in JavaScript. like this

```
        var global = { 
            !!str_replace('&quot;', '', json_encode($global))!!
        };
```

And this would result in an error `expected property name, got '!'`.
I uninstalled it, and instead installed [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shufo.vscode-blade-formatter). Now formatting is as expected with the blade directives in HTML being formatted correctly while those in JavaScript remain untouched.